# Taking backup in Solr

Tags: solr, backup

I have a doubt in Solr database backup. I want to know the number of records has been transferred from source to destination. Is it possible?

Comment: Just to clarify: Solr is not a database. It is a search engine built on top of lucene. What you want to backup is the lucene index itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a backup of the data folder. that's it.

Comment: Adding the configuration files in the backup will be a good idea too. Because if you lose them, you will have to recreate them.

Comment: @mavroprovato: yes. I agree. that's a good point. We should take backup of conf files too. Thanks.

Comment: You need to take the backup while Solr is not running though.

Comment: @javanna: Yes. That's recommended. Solr should be stopped or it should be pointed to another index. Thanks.

Comment: @All, Thanks for your response. I have implemented with your suggestions. I have another question. Is there any way to restore the back up data, without stopping the Solr server?

Answer (score 0):

In the SolrAdmin screen, you can see the number of docs in Solr:
http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Solr+Section

[image]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually I want the details that number of records has been transferred from source to destination while taking back up. is there any way to identify that?